# Better way to add a wordpress category class to a specific div based on category page via php

Tags: php, wordpress

In my goals to better understand how to use php efficiently, I was wondering if it was possible to add the wordpress category to a specific div on the single page template via php.

I have already accomplished this for adding the category to the body class via the function below:

```
// add category nicenames in body and post class
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_category_to_single' );

function add_category_to_single( $classes ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        global $post;
        foreach ( ( get_the_category( $post->ID ) ) as $category ) {
            // add category slug to the $classes array
            $classes[] = $category->category_nicename;
        }
    }
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

I've also technically accomplished this via the php snippet below (there are about 15 more of these not shown) :

```
<?php if (is_category('building-products')){
    echo '<div class="heading-container building"><div class="nhs-heading"><h1 id="pageName" class="entry-title">Building Products</h1></div></div>';
    } elseif (is_category('emergency-prepardness')) {
    echo '<div class="heading-container emergency"><div class="nhs-heading"><h1 id="pageName" class="entry-title">Emergency Preparedness</h1></div></div>';
    } else (is_category('energy-efficient-and-eco-friendly')) {
    echo '<div class="heading-container energy"><div class="nhs-heading"><h1 id="pageName" class="entry-title">Energy Efficient & Eco Friendly</h1></div></div>';
    } ?>
```

But in trying to better understand how to use php effectively is there a cleaner more efficient way to detect if the body has a specific class (building products for example) and then add the same category to the heading-container div or is the above snippet the only way via php?

Any resource pointing towards a better way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with a basic array mapping instead of having tons of if.

Here is a sample

```
$categoryToElement = [
    "building-products" => [
        "label" => "Building Products",
        "class" => "building"
    ],
    "emergency-prepardness" => [
        "label" => "Emergency Preparedness",
        "class" => "emergency"
    ],
    "energy-efficient-and-eco-friendly" => [
        "label" => "Energy Efficient & Eco Friendly",
        "class" => "energy"
    ],
]
```

Now that you have the mapping. I imagine you can get the category of the item with `getCategory()` method.
Just do this :

```
$category = $this->getCategory();
    echo '<div class="heading-container '.$categoryToElement[$category]['class'].'"><div class="nhs-heading"><h1 id="pageName" class="entry-title">'.$categoryToElement[$category]['label'].'</h1></div></div>';
```

This will allow you to have a clearer understanding of what's going on, and what changes with an eye glance.

Hope this helped.